# Remove all rows not containing values from range

Tags: vba, excel

Sheet "Data" has 3000+ rows containing 100+ customers in column O. Assume "Customers" A1 through A26 is:

```
a
b
c
d
e
...
z
```

The code is removing all except z, instead of all except a through z. I need to remove all customers from "Data" that aren't listed in column A on "Customers" sheet. Where am I going wrong? Changing "dontDelete" to below yields the same result. 26 can be substituted for 14, 7, etc and then that row's value becomes the only one remaining.

```
dontDelete = Array(Range("Customers!A1:A26")
```

I tried to paste the sub in here but it keeps giving me a formatting error in spite of the preview looking correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your exact sub, its hard to see what you need to change to correct this. However, if you are statically assigning the size of the array like this

```
Dim dontDelete(26) As String
```

you are actually defining the array as dontDelete(0,1,2...24,25,26). Then if your loop goes through 26 iterations, it will always end at 25, not 26.

I'd suggest starting off by declaring your array like this

```
Dim dontDelete(1 to 26) as String
```

and trying again to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: The range is dynamic, goes from A1 to A(x) depending on how many customers are to be included on the summary.

The values in A are not numeric or single letters, it's text including spaces, etc.

Comment: On second thought, your suggestion has pointed me in the right direction to resolve the issue. Thanks!